# Generate pandas dataframe from a dictionary whose values are lists of dictionaries of varying number

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to parse a JSON object into a DataFrame. The format of the object is this:

```
 {"219": [{"year": "2015", "code": "VU", "category": "Vulnerable"}, 
          {"year": "2008", "code": "VU", "category": "Vulnerable"}, 
          {"year": "2002", "code": "VU", "category": "Vulnerable"}, 
          {"year": "1996", "code": "VU", "category": "Vulnerable"}, 
          {"year": "1994", "code": "V", "category": "Vulnerable"}, 
          {"year": "1990", "code": "V", "category": "Vulnerable"}, 
          {"year": "1988", "code": "V", "category": "Vulnerable"}, 
          {"year": "1986", "code": "V", "category": "Vulnerable"}], 
  "561": [{"year": "2016", "code": "LC", "category": "Least Concern"}, 
          {"year": "2010", "code": "LC", "category": "Least Concern"}, 
          {"year": "2006", "code": "LC", "category": "Least Concern"}, 
          {"year": "1996", "code": "EN", "category": "Endangered"}, 
          {"year": "1994", "code": "R", "category": "Rare"}, 
          {"year": "1990", "code": "R", "category": "Rare"}, 
          {"year": "1988", "code": "R", "category": "Rare"}, 
          {"year": "1986", "code": "R", "category": "Rare"}], 
  "571": [{"year": "2016", "code": "LC", "category": "Least Concern"}, 
          {"year": "2008", "code": "LC", "category": "Least Concern"}, 
          {"year": "2004", "code": "LC", "category": "Least Concern"}, 
          {"year": "1996", "code": "LR/lc", "category": "Lower Risk/least concern"}]
          }
```

Ultimately, I want the DataFrame to use the keys as rows, `year` as columns (one column per year), and `code` as values. I don't need `category`. Also, each k-v pair can have a variable number of dictionaries inside the value's list (but always with the same `year`/`code`/`category` structure).

```
taxonid  1986 1988 1990  1994 1996 2002 2004 2006 2008 2010 2015 2016
219         V    V    V    V    VU   VU  NaN  NaN   VU  NaN   VU  NaN
561         R    R    R    R    EN  NaN  NaN   LC  NaN   LC  NaN   LC
571       NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN LR/lc  NaN   LC  NaN   LC  NaN  NaN   LC
```

Is there a way to generate the DataFrame so that I don't have to first declare all the years as columns? Not all years are represented here, and it would be great to have code that would create an updated df every time I receive the JSON object.

I've looked through numerous SO questions but nothing has helped to crack this so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `d` is your dictionary from the question, then this example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( ((k, *dd.values()) for k, v in d.items() for dd in v), columns=['taxid', 'year', 'code', 'category'] )
df = pd.pivot_table(df, values='code', index='taxid', columns='year', aggfunc='first')
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
year  1986 1988 1990 1994   1996 2002 2004 2006 2008 2010 2015 2016
taxid                                                              
219      V    V    V    V     VU   VU  NaN  NaN   VU  NaN   VU  NaN
561      R    R    R    R     EN  NaN  NaN   LC  NaN   LC  NaN   LC
571    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  LR/lc  NaN   LC  NaN   LC  NaN  NaN   LC
```

Comment: Thanks Andrej, that works perfectly. Two questions: in the first line, why did you choose a generator over a list comprehension? And what does `aggfunc` do in the second line?

Comment: @panopticonopolis I used generator, because It's wasteful to create temporary list and then copy it to the DataFrame. With generator, one skips this temporary list cration. `aggfunc='first'` is beacause I want only first value from the group (and values from `'code'` column are of type string).

Answer (score 1):

You have to read all the keys as a single dataframe, concatenate them and after pivot in order to create the index and columns:

```py
dict_to_load = {
    "219": [
        {"year": "2015", "code": "VU", "category": "Vulnerable"},
        {"year": "2008", "code": "VU", "category": "Vulnerable"},
        {"year": "2002", "code": "VU", "category": "Vulnerable"},
        {"year": "1996", "code": "VU", "category": "Vulnerable"},
        {"year": "1994", "code": "V", "category": "Vulnerable"},
        {"year": "1990", "code": "V", "category": "Vulnerable"},
        {"year": "1988", "code": "V", "category": "Vulnerable"},
        {"year": "1986", "code": "V", "category": "Vulnerable"},
    ],
    "561": [
        {"year": "2016", "code": "LC", "category": "Least Concern"},
        {"year": "2010", "code": "LC", "category": "Least Concern"},
        {"year": "2006", "code": "LC", "category": "Least Concern"},
        {"year": "1996", "code": "EN", "category": "Endangered"},
        {"year": "1994", "code": "R", "category": "Rare"},
        {"year": "1990", "code": "R", "category": "Rare"},
        {"year": "1988", "code": "R", "category": "Rare"},
        {"year": "1986", "code": "R", "category": "Rare"},
    ],
    "571": [
        {"year": "2016", "code": "LC", "category": "Least Concern"},
        {"year": "2008", "code": "LC", "category": "Least Concern"},
        {"year": "2004", "code": "LC", "category": "Least Concern"},
        {"year": "1996", "code": "LR/lc", "category": "Lower Risk/least concern"},
    ],
}

dfs = []
for key, value in dict_to_load.items():
    df = (
        pd.DataFrame.from_dict(value)
        .reset_index(drop=True)
        .assign(taxonid=lambda x: [key] * len(x))  # create the column for the future index
        .drop(['category'], axis='columns')  # drop useless column
    )
    dfs.append(df)
final_df = pd.concat(dfs, axis='rows').pivot(
    index='taxonid', columns='year', values='code'
)
```

I suppose that the dictionary is already read and assign to a variable (`dict_to_load` in my example).

Answer (score 0):

Try this ( f is your json ):

```
df7 = pd.DataFrame()
df7.append([pd.io.json.json_normalize(f[x]).assign(taxonid=x) for x in f.keys()]).drop(columns='category').pivot(index='taxonid', columns='year', values='code')                     


year    1986 1988 1990 1994   1996 2002 2004 2006 2008 2010 2015 2016
taxonid                                                              
219        V    V    V    V     VU   VU  NaN  NaN   VU  NaN   VU  NaN
561        R    R    R    R     EN  NaN  NaN   LC  NaN   LC  NaN   LC
571      NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  LR/lc  NaN   LC  NaN   LC  NaN  NaN   LC
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get `TypeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object is not subscriptable` when I try to run it.